# Send Email from SMTP remote server CakePHP 3

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp

I'm facing some problems configuring my app to send Mails from my smtp server, which is located in one remote hosting with 1and1.
I don't know if I'm missing something:

- I've changed my app.php to the values given by my hosting provider:

  ```
  'EmailTransport' => [
      'default' => [
          'className' => 'Mail',
          'host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
          'port' =>'587' ,
          'timeout' => 30,
          'username' => 'me@dns.com',
          'password' => '******',
          'client' => null,
          'tls' => null,
      ],
  ],

  'Email' => [
      'default' => [
          'transport' => 'default',
          'from' => '@localhost',
          //'charset' => 'utf-8',
          //'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
      ],
  ],
  ```

Here you can see the instructions given by my hosting provider to connect to their smtp server.

[image: smtp requiere comfig]

I don't get any result. 
 Does anybody have an Idea what may I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working setting classname as 'Mail' and the rest of the parameters as default. Please, do as follows:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'client' => null,

        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case only was problem in className.

For using gmail or office365 server it should be so:

```
'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'smtp.office365.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'my@email.com',
            'password' => 'myPassword',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => true,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do as following:

```
//Adding Smtp information for sending mail through smtp instead of php mail function on local server / live server

'EmailTransport' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.1and1.com',
        'port' =>'587' ,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'me@dns.com',
        'password' => '******',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => null,
    ],
],
```

You can also enable tls to `'tls' => true` if required.